# Can I put a class in a generic class declaration?

Tags: java, generics

I want to know if there is a way to do something like this:

```
Class clazz = Class.forname("java.lang.String");
GenericClass <clazz> generic = new GenericClass <clazz>();
```

putting a class into a generic class parameter.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you might need to do this? There might be an easier way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: No, you can't. You might be able to create a generic type through reflection but this syntax requires a type parameter, not a variable.

Comment: @immibis i need to create a form based on XML Flux , so i need to loop over the fields of the objectcs... so i tought if i can do a géneric class without checking which class was passed.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

However, if you know what you're doing, you don't strictly *need* the generic parameter. You can use a **raw type**:

```
GenericClass generic = new GenericClass();
```

Java uses "erasure" to implement generics - which means that if you write something like `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`, the compiler will check that you never try to put anything that's not a String in it, but then it will throw away (erase) the generics and convert it to `List l = new ArrayList();`.

Since a `GenericClass<Anything>` is really just a `GenericClass` under the hood, you can use a `GenericClass` directly. You will get a compiler warning whenever you use it, and you have to be extra-careful to only give it the right kind of object, but sometimes it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

No. Generics are evaluated at compile time, while the code would be run later at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, your specific problem might be solvable by using another generic method. For example, this method creates a `List` containing an instance of a given `Class`:

```
<T> List<T> createListOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    result.add(clazz.newInstance());
    return result;
}
```

It could then be called like this, without knowing the actual types:

```
Class<?> unknownClass = Class.forName(unknownString);
List<?> listOfUnknownClass = createListOf(unknownClass);
```

(Without more information, I can't make this answer more specific to your particular problem)

Comment: @Saint because they are different.